# similarity check on vectors in postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I was using pg_similarity extension for checking similarity of values. Now I have bag of words instead of text as values. I tried smlar extension:

```
select smlar( a.tokenizedsentence, b.tokenizedSentence ) from nlpdata a, nlpdata b;
```

But got error:

```
ERROR:  function smlar(character varying, character varying) does not exist
LINE 1: select smlar(a.tokenizedsentence, b.tokenizedsentence) from ...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Then I tried:

```
select smlar(a.tokenizedsentence::varchar[], b.tokenizedsentence::varchar[]) from nlpdata a, nlpdata b;
```

And got:

```
ERROR:  malformed array literal: "0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1"
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
```

Tried to search for any postgres extension for vectors, but could not find any. Any ideas or maybe information about some extensions?

Edit: now it calculates, but answer always is 0.707 or 1, even though it is wrong.

Comment: Mistake in copying from terminal. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

You can only cast a string directly to an array type if it conforms to the array literal format (for example, `{a,b,c}`).

But in general, you construct arrays using the various [supporting functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html). In your case, you probably want something like:

```
smlar(string_to_array(a.tokenizedsentence, ' '), string_to_array(b.tokenizedsentence, ' '))
```

Comment: Now it runs, but does not calculate correctly. Result is 0.707 or 1. But anyway thanks.